# facebook sharer not working as expected

Tags: facebook

The following works fine when tested on my local version of the facebook tab, but once inserted inside facebook the window doesn't open:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/ArlaWingCo/app_141940199343551
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Check your Javascript console to see if there are any errors

Comment: Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/ArlaWingCo/app_141940199343551' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12108734/254973) says that adding a `target="_top"` seems to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Can you navigate the url ,oops I cant !

https://www.facebook.com/ArlaWingCo/app_141940199343551

otherwise no problem

> Like
>   https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://stackoverflow.com/